# macro_rules! macro takes string literal "...", expands to both "..." and b"..."

Tags: macros, rust

I would like to write a `macro_rules!` macro whose arguments are one `ident` and a list of string literals.  The expansion of the macro needs to contain both the string literals, and the corresponding *byte* literals. The macro is for tests, and will only ever be used with strings containing only characters in the U+0000 ... U+007F range.  It is OK if supplying anything other than string literals to the macro causes a compile-time error.

If this isn't currently possible without resorting to procedural macros, just tell me so, don't bother actually writing the procedural macro ;-)

The desired invocation and expansion is like this:

```
all_s! isalpha [ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" /* , ... */ ];
```

=>

```
assert!(isalpha("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
assert!("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars().all(|b| isalpha(b));
assert!(isalpha(b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
assert!(b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".iter().all(|b| isalpha(b)));
/* ... */
```

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
macro_rules! all_s {
    ($what: ident, $( $str: tt ),* ) => {{
        $(
            assert!($what($str));
            assert!($str.chars().all(|b| $what(b));
            assert!($what(BYTE_LITERAL!($str)));
            assert!(BYTE_LITERAL!($str).iter().all(|b| $what(b)));
        )*
    }}
}
```

but I don't know what to put where it says `BYTE_LITERAL!`, and also I'm getting error messages that suggest that I haven't written the match pattern correctly, e.g. "macro all_s! expects no ident argument, given 'isalpha'" when '$what:ident' is right there.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert a literal to another type of literal; it's just not how macros work.

You *can* convert a `&str` to a `&[u8]` via [`str::as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes):

```
fn is_alpha<T>(_: T) -> bool { true }

macro_rules! all_s {
    ($what: ident, $str: tt) => {{
        assert!($what($str));
        assert!($str.chars().all(|b| $what(b)));
        assert!($what($str.as_bytes()));
        assert!($str.as_bytes().iter().all(|b| $what(b)));
    }};
}

fn main() {
    all_s!(is_alpha, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a disappointing limitation in the macro system, but this will probably do for a workaround for something used only for tests.

Comment: @zwol it's no more a "limitation" than the fact that you can't transform an macro argument of an `ident` into a `type`; or a `String` to a `Vec`, for that matter. Different types mean different things.

Comment: Frankly, I think _all_ of the things you mention _should_ be possible in a macro.  You're rewriting the text of the program.  You should be able to do so arbitrarily.

Comment: @zwol ah, perhaps that root of the problem. Rust macros do **not** work on the *text* of the program, they operate on the AST; they are not C macros. That's why the macro arguments take types like `ident` - those map to a grammar production.

Comment: I understand that they operate on the AST, but that should only limit them to producing well-formed ASTs -- they should still be able to do things like changing the types of literals.

Answer (score 2):

> I also don't know how to reject `tt`s that aren't string literals.

If you make use of the fact that the arguments are strings, then the typechecker will take care of producing errors.

```
macro_rules! all_s {
    ($what: ident, $( $str: tt ),* ) => {{
        $(
            assert!($what($str));
            assert!(str::chars($str).all(|c| char::is_alphabetic(c)));
            assert!(str::chars($str).all(|c| char::is_alphabetic(c)));
        )*
    }}
}
```

In your question code, you are trying to use the same `isalpha` with values of both `char` and `u8`. You'll have to convert the `char`s to `u8`s first:

```
assert!(str::chars($str)
            .map(|c| c as u8) // this is safe given the assumption you stated
            .all(|b| b < 0x7F));
```

Comment: Okay, but that's the least important part of the question ;-)

Comment: @zwol with your high reputation, I'd think you'd know [not to ask multiple questions in one post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). Doing so allows valid answers like this.

Comment: @Shepmaster It is one question, namely "how do I write a macro that does _all_ of the following things: ...?"